# How to add a simple direction to and from here within the infowindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am moving my Google multipoint map from version 2 to 3.
I can show the icons and open new windows when clicked which is fine but on version 2 when the info window was opened there was an option "Directions to here and from here". When either to here or from here were clicked a text field would appear and you could enter the name of a town for instance. When clicking the button the user was sent to Google maps in a new windows.
I don't seem to be able to find such option.
Here is the script I had on version 2:

```
// The info window version with the "to here" form open
    to_htmls[i] = html + '<br>Directions: <b>To here</b> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')">From here</a>' +
       '<br>Start address:<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">' +
       '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br>' +
       '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT">' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="' + point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() + 
              // "(" + name + ")" + 
       '"/>';
    // The info window version with the "to here" form open
    from_htmls[i] = html + '<br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')">To here</a> - <b>From here</b>' +
       '<br>End address:<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get"" target="_blank">' +
       '<input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40 name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br>' +
       '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT">' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="saddr" value="' + point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() +
              // "(" + name + ")" + 
       '"/>';
    // The inactive version of the direction info
    html = html + '<br><br>Directions: <a href="javascript:tohere('+i+')">To here</a> - <a href="javascript:fromhere('+i+')">From here</a>';
```

Comment: None of the code you posted is Google Maps API v2 specific.  You need to either provide more context or a link to your map (or a jsfiddle) where you tried to do this and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4.html) is one of the pages that code appears in from [Mike Williams' Google Maps v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic4.htm), translated to v3.